# PDO connection is not closed when phpunit is running with symfony 2.X

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, connection, phpunit

We have about 180 unit tests implement `webtestcase` class and tests are running over controllers.

However when we run the unit tests, they open too many connection to db. Because of too many active tcp connection test are fail after 120th test. All the connection are active while tests are running.

In the tearDown function we call the close function of entity manager, but there is nothing, it doesn't any affect. There is some class keeping the connection object reference, i think.

Because in php manual mentioned about pdo connection closed when the object assigned to null. We also do that but no changes.
P.S: Our unit tests are functional tests. Works over controller and integrated with db, there is no mock objects

Where is our mistake ? How can we fix the problem?

This my connection parameters in config_test.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: config_dev.yml }

framework:
    test: ~
    session:
        storage_id: session.storage.mock_file

web_profiler:
    toolbar: false
    intercept_redirects: false

doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        port: 3306
        host: localhost
        dbname: mydb
        user: myuser
        password: mypass
        charset: UTF8
```

Comment: Can we see how you define your connection inside config.yml file and/or parameters.yml?

Comment: @j0k I added to question

Comment: I had similar problem some time ago. The problem happened because of unfinished transaction. Do you use explicitly transaction (I mean begin-commit/rollback)? If so, make sure that you always finish it.

Comment: Hmm, I have another guess. How do you close these connections? Do you close entity manager from the client? If you don't - you should close entity manager from the client: $this->client->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')->close();

Comment: @Cyprian I have no transaction. If doctrine by default uses transactional then I don't know. Yes I close connection as you said.

Comment: I didn't close any connection in controller, repository or somewhere else. I closed it in test class. `self::kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')->close()` something like that. Should I have closed it in application context ? I think that php automatically closes it when request ends. @Cyprian

Comment: No, you should close in your test (as you do it now). But instead of closing entity manager from the kernel, close the one from client, as I wrote before: $this->client->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')->close();

Comment: Ok. I will try and inform you. thank you @Cyprian

Comment: We have tried but nothing has changed. We closed connection both in test classes and the end of the actions of controller. Do you have another suggestion @Cyprian

Comment: I resolve the problem in Silex with following setup in tearDown() method:

        $this->app['db']->close();

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you check your phpunit.xml.dist file?

I think you should look at this; 
http://www.slideshare.net/fabpot/unit-and-functional-testing-with-symfony2

Be sure your parameters are the same below

```
<phpunit
    backupGlobals               = "false"
    backupStaticAttributes      = "false"
    colors                      = "true"
    convertErrorsToExceptions   = "true"
    convertNoticesToExceptions  = "true"
    convertWarningsToExceptions = "true"
    processIsolation            = "true"
    stopOnFailure               = "false"
    syntaxCheck                 = "false" 
    bootstrap                   = "bootstrap.php.cache" >
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I found the solution. Apparently the processIsolation parameter caused the problem. It was a false, because of this whole tests work on one process and I think it kept parameterers. But after I changed it into true, connections closed after each test ended. @bulutcagatay

Comment: Interesting that this brings another problem: "Uncaught PDOException: You cannot serialize or unserialize PDO instances".

Comment: This is all well and good but when you set processIsolation to "true" any assertion failure then results in an obscure error about being unable to serialize a closure.

Answer (score 5):

Enabling process isolation will have the side effect of making the test suite absurdly much more slow to execute.

A better approach is to just tell Doctrine explicitly to close its connections, either on test tearDown, tearDownAfterClass or any method annotated as such, like for example:

```
trait CloseConnectionAfterTestTrait {
    /** @after */
    public function avoidExhaustingDbConnections()
    {
        if(!empty($this->em)){
            $this->em->getConnection()->close();
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, it is up to the consumer to save whatever entity manager instance he has as `$this->em`. But if/since you use Doctrine you could probably generalize the code better by accessing the Doctrine service through `static::$kernel->something`.

Comment: I have added the code to close connection after each test - but still no effect...